# why does setBackgroundDrawable() return null when passing an object but, works fine while using anonymous class

Tags: android

I want to change the color of ActionBar. I used this:

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(" #070b2e"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

It crashed the app and gave this warning:

> Method invocation 'setBackgroundDrawable' may produce
> 'NullPointerException'

but when I write this instead,

```
     getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#070b2e")));
```

It works fine, App doesn't crash, color is changed now. however, warning still remains.

Comment: 1. That not an anonymous class, that's simply using object of ColorDrawable instead of storing in an instance 2. Please post your crash logs.  3. The warning say that  getSupportActionBar() may be null so you need to add a null check for safety.

Comment: @AsthaGarg idk why but App doesn't crash in first code now , and for the warning , i added `if(getSupportActionBar() != null)` for null checking and it worked. Thank You.

Comment: Yes both codes are same, it can't happen that it may crash with 1st code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that's not an anonymous class, that's simply using an object of `ColorDrawable` instead of storing it in an instance.

The warning says that `getSupportActionBar()` may be null so you need to add a null check for safety.

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    ...your code..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash on your first code seems caused by the space on " #070b2e" string  - `parseColor` method doesn't do space trimming